# ActiveMq in combination with Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, activemq-classic

I would like to create an ActiveMQ MessageListener and configured it using Spring.

I will host the listener in Tomcat. I don't know if this flow can be done? If so, how?

Client ---> Tomcat--->ActiveMQ---->Service(Java Application) ---->ActiveMQ--->Tomcat--->Client

Comment: Please see this question. I need exactly the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am only using Jersey Rest service not spring framework. I have to keep all incomeing request in a queue and then forward to the resource and get the result. Main point is that handling all the http requests properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done. Have a look at the [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html). Inside your Spring configuration inside your web application you could then have:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" ref="brokerUrl" />
</bean>

<bean id="container" 
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
  <property name="destination" ref="queue" />
  <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener" />
  <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
</bean>
```

Where myMessageListener is a reference to your MessageListener.

Regarding your question on what the flow would look like, it would be:

- JMS Client sends a message to a queue on the ActiveMQ broker
- The ActiveMQ broker receives the message and passes it on to one of the consumers listening to that queue, in this case our MessageListener inside Tomcat

Comment: sure that data can be replied to correct client's session? Give me more information

Comment: if you want a response to go to the right client session, you'll need to set up a temporary queue and set it as the replyTo in your client application when you send the JMS message.

Comment: Client uses web browser to send data--> ActiveMQ->Service->ActiveMq->Client?

Comment: How is the browser talking to ActiveMQ? Is it through the ActiveMQ REST, WebSockets or Ajax interface? Or is the thought that you'll have the web browser talk to a servlet hosted in your Tomcat that will then pass the message on to ActiveMQ?

Comment: And you'd like that servlet to receive a web request from a browser and then pass that as a message to ActiveMQ?

Comment: @JamieMcCrindle Hi, Please guide me on this. Thanks for your time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/integration-of-restful-web-service-with-activemq

Answer (score 0):

Yes. and I have a service that solves these data and then send result to ActiveMq and then show the result to client

Comment: Anh Please look on this. Thanks for your time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration